# QR Code reader in webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, qr-code

I'm looking for a way to make something very similar to this http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/05/23/introduction-of-qr-code-reader-library/ on my asp MVC 3 project. It is a QR Code Reader, not generator. I want it to be displayed on a View and serve as an input.

Could anybody point me in the right direction to do this? Any links or library info would be appreciated.